# How to avoid repetitive if statements in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dynamic, dictionary, if-statement, repeat

I am trying to create a new dictionary out of html form data that was submitted by the user. I end up writing repetitive if statements, checking if xyz key is in the dictionary in the form data. I know this is a quite suboptimal approach though I am not quite sure how to implement this using python.

This is the form data dictionary:

```
form_data = {
'urls': ['www.google.com', 'www.bing.com'],
'useremail': ['my@email.com'],
'emailfield': ['1'],
'addressfield': ['1'],
'addressfield_info':['Company'],
'addressfield_instruction': ['Please only if the company is a LLC'],
'phonefield': ['1'],
'phonefield_instruction': ['please include area code']
}
```

and I want to create a dictionary that looks like this:

```
new_dic = {
'urls': ['www.google.com', 'www.bing.com'],
'useremail': ['my@email.com'],
'infofield': [
              {'field': 'email'},
              {'field': 'address', 'info':'Company', 'instruction': 'Please only if the company is a LLC'},
              {'field':'phone', 'instruction': 'please include area code'}
             ]
}
```

Important note: The 'xyzfield' is mandatory and the 'xyzfield_info' and 'xyzfield_instruction' are both optional. Also: the user can add more fields and create for instance an 'agefield', 'agefield_info' and 'agefield_instruction'.

The problem I have is about how to efficiently check if xyzfield (email, phone, etc) is in the dictionary. If it is in there, check also if any of the optional fields are in there as well. This looks currently something like this:

```
if 'emailfield' in form_data:
    infofield = {'field': 'email'}
    if 'emailfield_info' in form_data:
         infofield['info'] = form_data['emailfield_info']
    if 'emailfield_instruction' in form_data:
         infofield['instruction'] = form_data['emailfield_instruction']

cleaned_data['infofields'].append(infofield)

...
```

and I do this for every field, hence I have 4-5 of this. Additional, I will not be able to process any of the fields that the user has created himself since I don't know the name upfront.

Long story short: How can I make this more efficient and dynamic?

Comment: Please be more consistent about variable names (`new_dic` is `cleaned_data`, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard answer to how to avoid repeated code applies here --- extract the repeated code to a function:

```
def extract_field(form_data, clean, fieldname, optional=('info', 'instruction')):
   if fieldname+'field' in form_data:
       infofield = { 'field': fieldname }
       for opt in optional:
           optname = '{}field_{}'.format(fieldname, opt)
           if optname in form_data:
              infofield[opt] = form_data[optname]
       clean.append(infofield)

extract_field(form_data, cleaned_data['infofields'], 'email')
extract_field(form_data, cleaned_data['infofields'], 'address')
extract_field(form_data, cleaned_data['infofields'], 'phone')
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you just want to clean whatever is actually submitted.  If you are looking for specific things to be there, I suggest making a list of things to look for, and iterating over the list and checking to see if the things are there.

```
form_data = {
    'urls': ['www.google.com', 'www.bing.com'],
    'useremail': ['my@email.com'],
    'emailfield': ['1'],
    'addressfield': ['1'],
    'addressfield_info':['Company'],
    'addressfield_instruction': ['Please only if the company is a LLC'],
    'phonefield': ['1'],
    'phonefield_instruction': ['please include area code']
}

def make_field_dict(form_data, base):
        field_dict = {}

        name_field = base + "field"
        name_info = base + "field_info"
        name_inst = base + "field_instruction"
        if name_field not in form_data:
            raise KeyError, "%s not found in form_data" % name_field
        if form_data[name_field] != ['1']:
            raise ValueError, "%s not valid in form_data" % name_field
        field_dict["field"] = base
        if name_info in form_data:
            lst = form_data[name_info]
            if len(lst) != 1:
                raise ValueError, "%s not valid in form_data" % name_info
            field_dict["info"] = lst[0]
        if name_inst in form_data:
            lst = form_data[name_inst]
            if len(lst) != 1:
                raise ValueError, "%s not valid in form_data" % name_inst
            field_dict["instruction"] = lst[0]
        return field_dict

def parse_form_data(form_data):
    cleaned_data = {}
    cleaned_data["infofield"] = []
    seen = set()
    for key, value in form_data.items():
        if "field" not in key:
            cleaned_data[key] = value
        else:
            base, _, tail = key.partition("field")
            if base in seen:
                continue
            cleaned_data["infofield"].append(make_field_dict(form_data, base))
            seen.add(base)
    return cleaned_data


new_dic = {
'urls': ['www.google.com', 'www.bing.com'],
'useremail': ['my@email.com'],
'infofield': [
              {'field': 'email'},
              {'field': 'address', 'info':'Company', 'instruction': 'Please only if the company is a LLC'},
              {'field':'phone', 'instruction': 'please include area code'}
             ]
}

clean_data = parse_form_data(form_data)

new_dic['infofield'].sort()
clean_data['infofield'].sort()
assert(new_dic == clean_data)
```